# Need assistance in R, usinf a "for" loop to read in multiple .csv files and assign them names so that the files can then be worked on

Tags: r, csv

In R, I am making a function that requires reading in 1:n csv files, how to I name each file in a "for" loop and save.  I have tried `test[i] <- read.csv(paste0("0", "0", i, sep="")` and I get a "closure" error.  I have searched through Stack Overflow and found similar questions but nothing like I am looking for. I am using also 1 "if" statement and two "else if" statements in the "for" loop.  There are 3 different paste0 functions, `paste0("0", "0", i, ".csv", sep = "")`, `paste0("0", i, ".csv" sep = "")`, and `paste0(i, ".csv", sep "")`

I just signed up to Stack Overflow today and I am new to R.  I am sorry if I overlooked the question and it has been answered.

What I am looking for is something like `name_test[1] <- 001.csv` and so on.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061

Comment: Lots on this problem already on SO - try Googling for "stackoverflow getmonitor".  Instead of using `paste0` and a loop to read the files, consider `list.files()` with argument `full.names = TRUE` to get the list of files in a directory - then you can use `lapply` with `read.csv` to process, as described elsewhere on StackOverflow.  Such an approach would be useful even if they weren't all named `001.csv`, `002.csv`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this will work (not tested):

```
test <- lapply(1:n, function(i) read.csv(paste(sprintf("%03d", i), "csv", sep=".")))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import all the data into a list, you can try this

```
# Get the list of files in the folder
db.name.list<-list.files(path="path", pattern="*.csv")
# Read in all the data into a list of dataframe
db.name.path<-paste("path",db.name.list, sep="/")
db<-lapply(db.name.path, read.csv, header=T)
names(db)<-db.name.list
```